# Is there a StackOverflow Dark Theme for VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to obtain the Stackoverflow theme for VsCode? Is this theme called something specific?

[image: Example of what I see]

Comment: @user this is super close though. perhaps I could just use this as a base and make the background dark? Not sure how to change an existing them but maybe I can google it.